# systemd service for automated ssh proxy upon wifi connection

Tags: ssh, networking, systemd

*Edit: I always have little luck with systemd questions... is there a good tutorial available? I think 90% of tasks I have are related to start something at login or whenever a wifi connection is available. Anyone can point to a good resource?*

---

I'm trying to start a ssh proxy upon connecting to WiFi automatically.

While the script that is called by the service itself works, and the service also starts correctly, my proxy doesn't work. Also, upon disconnecting and reconnecting from the WiFi, the service doesn't restart, i.e. once I disconnect, the service becomes inactive, rather than waiting for the next WiFi connection.

Why does the service not correctly provide the ssh socks proxy? How can I change the service file so that it retriggers upon each WiFi connection?

```
# ssh_proxy.sh (744)   
ssh -D 8123 user@remote.server
```

```
# ssh_proxy.service
[Unit]
Description=Create an SSH proxy once a WiFi connection is available
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/home/user
ExecStart=/home/user/ssh_proxy.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Does it work if you start the service manually? Also, consider adding a shebang to the top of your script (`#!/bin/sh`)

Comment: It works if I enter the command in a terminal `ssh -D...` but not  when starting the service with `systemctl start ssh_proxy.service`